# Header-only library with CMake logic - how to treat in Conan?

Tags: cmake, package-management, header-only, conanfile

I'm the author of a header-only library, which I want to make available via Conan. So, I'm writing a `conanfile.py` for it.

The Conan documentation suggests a path for this, when your project is header only: You don't build anything and sources get copied. However, in my case, my `CMakeLists.txt` defines dependencies, "partitions" the library into distinct targets, and exports CMake package configuration files (in addition to installing the header files at an appropriate location).

So, should I let go of all of the "CMake stuff"? If not, how do I express the need to use `CMakeList.txt`?